# Can we generalize the concept of "characters" in group theory via methods from statistics and probability theory?

Tags: pr.probability, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, st.statistics, harmonic-analysis

$\DeclareMathOperator\Cov{Cov}$**Motivation:** If $G$ is a finite group and $\phi=X+iY: G\to \mathbb{T}$ is a character of $G$, then   $\Cov(X,Y)=0$ where $X$, $Y$ are considered as two real random variables on $G$.

Based on this motivation we consider the following generalization:

---

Assume that  $G$  is a finite group. Let $\phi=X+iY: G\to S^1$ be a complex function of unit norm.
We consider $G$ as a sample (probability)  space  with the normalized counting measure  $\mu(A)=\frac{\lvert A\rvert}{\lvert G\rvert}$.  So we consider  $X$, $Y$  as two random variables. Their covariance is denoted by $\Cov(X,Y)$.

> Is the following set $H$ a group with the operation of pointwise multiplication $(\phi\cdot\psi)(x)=\phi(x)\cdot\psi(x)$?
> $$H=\bigl\{\phi=X+iY:G\to S^1  \bigm| ( \phi\equiv1) \lor  \bigl(\sum_g \phi(g)=0 \land  \Cov(X,Y)=0 \bigr ) \bigr \}.$$

**Remark 1:** Every character $\phi:G\to S^1=\mathbb{T}$ obviously belongs to $H$. So this question is an attempt to find a generalization of characters in group theory in the context of probability and statistics.

**Remark 2:** What about if we remove the condition $\sum_g \phi(g)=0$ from the definition of $H$ above?

**Edit** After the comment by Yemon Choi I realize the group structure of $G$ does not play a crucial role in the question. We merely use the counting measure or more generally the Haar measure. But we can consider this question as a possible search for the  following. In fact the implicit and initial goal of this post was:

> Some (maximal) group extension $H$ of character group whose elements satisfy "uncorrelation property" (or/and "zero-mean property"). In particular for a finit or LCA group $G$, is the character group $\hat{G}$ maximal with respect to uncorrelation property $\Cov(X,Y)=0$ for all  $\phi=X+iY$. In the other words: can one say that there is no any  group $H$ with the following property:
> $\hat{G}\subsetneq H \subset \mathcal{W}$ such that for every $\phi=X+iY \in H$ we have $Cov(X,Y)=0$ where $\mathcal{W}=\{f:G\to \mathbb{T} \bigm|f\quad \text{is continuous}\}$

Please see this related post:
[Complex multiplication of two uncorrelated pair of unit norm](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395254/complex-multiplication-of-two-uncorrelated-pair-of-unit-norm).

**Remark 3:** As a generalization of the first lines of this post, the motivation part, one can consider a finite dimensional representation of a group. Then one associate some pair of uncorrelated random variables to this representation. In the motivation part we associate the uncorrelated pair $(X,Y)$

Comment: What do you get for the non-abelian group of order 6?

Comment: @YemonChoi  Thank you for your comment. i revise the question

Comment: Thanks, but to repeat my earlier comment: if you have come up with some question about finite groups, which works for all abelian groups, what have you tried to do for the simplest possible non-abelian group, to decide if your proposed definition is likely to be worthwhile or sensible?

Comment: @LSpice  Dear Loren Thank you very much for your revise.

Comment: @YemonChoi  may be a more necessary comment could be: "What is the role of group structure in your question"?